# Interview - finding even sum pair in an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Given an array , how would you return the number of pairs which sum to an even number?

For example:

```
a[] = { 2 , -6 , 1, 3, 5 }
```

In this array , the nos which pair to an even sum are
(2,-6), (1,3) , (1,5),  (3,5)

Function should return 4 as there are 4 pairs or -1 if none.

Expected time complexity - O(N) worst case
Expected space complexity - O(N) worst case

Approach 1:
Brute force

```
Start with the first number
  Start with second number
      assign the sum to a temp variable
      check if the temp is even
          If it is increment evenPair count
      else
          increment the second index
```

Here the time complexity is O(N2)

Comment: Two numbers will sum to an even number if either both are even or both are odd, so you should be able to work it out by simply counting the number of odd and even numbers in the array and from there the possible number of valid pairs. You don't need to actually to do all the additions if all you want is the number of pairs.

Comment: But how will find the possible pairs if you don't add them ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter u can actually post it as the answer!

Comment: @aba123 Simply count odd numbers and even numbers in a sequence. Then you can use well-known mathematical formula ( n! / 2! * ( n - 2)!) to calculate the number of sums. For example if there is n = 4 even numbers in a sequence then there will be 6 even sums and so on.

Comment: Do the numbers repeat? Example: {1,2,3,2,1}

Comment: _"how would you return the number of pairs which sum to an even number?"_ - with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 8):

```
int odd = 0, even = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    } else {
        odd++;
    }
}
int answer = (odd * (odd - 1) + even * (even - 1)) / 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If to use standard algorithms then the code can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 2 , -6 , 1, 3, 5 };

    typedef size_t Odd, Even;
    auto p = std::accumulate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 
                              std::pair<Odd, Even>( 0, 0 ),
                              []( std::pair<Odd, Even> &acc, int x )
                              {
                                return x & 1 ? ++acc.first : ++acc.second, acc;
                              } );

    std::cout << "There are " 
              << ( p.first * ( p.first - 1 ) + p.second * ( p.second - 1 ) ) / 2
              << " even sums" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
There are 4 even sums
```

Take into account that `n! / ( 2! * ( n - 2 )! )` is equivalent to  `( n - 1 ) * n / 2`

The advantage of using the standard algorithm is that you can use any subrange of a sequence. Also you can use a standard stream input because `std::accumulate` uses input iterator.

Also it would be much better if in the description of the assignment there would be written that the function should return 0 instead of -1 if there is no even sums among elements of an array.

It is not shameful to show this code in an interview though I advice **never** do any assignments in an interview. Interview is not an exam.

Answer (score 2):

If a and b are even, a + b is even.
If they're odd, a + b is also even.
If one is odd and one is even, a + b is odd.

This means that we don't need to perform any additions, we only need to know how many numbers there are of each kind.
Finding this out takes linear time.

If you have k numbers, there are k - 1 pairs that include the first number, k - 2 involving the second, and so on.
Using the familiar summation formula, `sum(1 .. n) = (n * (n + 1)) / 2`,

let

```
ne = number of even numbers
no = number of odd numbers
```

then,

```
number of pairs = (ne-1) * ne / 2 + (no-1) * no / 2 
                = ((ne-1)*ne + (no-1)*no) / 2
```

That computation runs in constant time, so the time complexity is still linear.

And we only need a constant amount of extra space, which is better than the requirements.

---

Possible followup interview questions possibly worth thinking about:

What happens to the complexities (both in time and space) if:

- duplicates are only counted once, i.e. `{1,1,1,2}` only has two such pairs?
- we disregard order, i.e. `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` are the "same" pair?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be compute the number of sums by even and odds, and then sum then together

```
int sumO = 0 , sumE = 0 , numO = 0 , numE = 0;
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        sumE += numE;
        numE ++;
    }
    else
    {
        sumO += numO;
        numO ++;
    }
}

printf ("Total: %d\n", sumO + sumE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this question from an interview.
No need to total even and odd both separate.

```
public static int evenTotalPairs(int[] A) {
int size = A.length;
int evens = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
    if(A[i] % 2 == 0){
        evens++;
    }
}
return evens*(evens-1)/2 + (size-evens)*(size-evens-1)/2;
```

}